# Как передать в callback delay в функцию debounce?

Tags: javascript

Как передать в callback delay ? Так не работает

```
   const func = debounce(function (array = [], delay) {
        ...//
    }, delay);

   export default (fn, time) => {
     let timeout;

     return function() {
      const functionCall = () => fn.apply(this, arguments);

      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
     };
  };
```

Comment: Что не работает?

Comment: delay переданный не видит

Comment: покажи что не видит

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cndz9a26/1/
вот так не работает
не могу пробросить delay в колбэк

Comment: говорит что unresolved variable

Comment: `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: я просто скопировала. код нерабочий

Answer (score 0):

```js
const debounce = (fn, time) => {
    let timeout;

    return function() {
        const functionCall = () => fn.apply(this, arguments);

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
    };
};

const delay = 1000;

const append = debounce(
  () => {
    console.log("three");
  },
  delay
);

console.log("one");
append();
console.log("two");
```